# Package check and logic; is.element

Tags: r

This may be another repeat of this issue but here we go.

I'm building a .Rprofile package checker. I also use a similar script for r scripts I send to my coworkers who are not technical. It checks for packages and installs them if they are not there and loads them if they are. I found a bunch of resources on package checking but for some reason as soon as you start sticking these checks into functions or the .Rprofile things get strange.

if someone could tell me what is wrong with this function it would be a huge help. I am really scratching my head on this.

```
startup_packagecheck<-function(pkg){
  library("utils")
  if(!is.element(pkg, installed.packages()))
    return(TRUE)
}
startup_packagecheck(pkg=MASS)
```

Comment: What happens when you run this, and how does it differ from what you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

In the question, the object passed to the function is named `MASS`. This object should exist in the `.GlobalEnv` and is unrelated to the character string `"MASS"`, needed to have `is.element` see if it's an element of the character vector returned by `installed.packages`.

The way to solve the problem is to pass character strings to the function.

```
startup_packagecheck<-function(pkg){
  !is.element(pkg, utils::installed.packages())
}

startup_packagecheck(pkg = MASS)
#[1] FALSE

Packs <- c("MASS", "ggplot2")
startup_packagecheck(pkg = Packs)
#[1] FALSE FALSE
```